# Usage of touch with pipeline

Tags: touch

I want to be able to use the `touch` command with the pipeline to create multiple files depending on the output of a command.

Like for example:

```bsh
grep "hello(.*)" file.txt | touch
```

But it doesn't work!
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `touch` command itself cannot read from `stdin`, but you can do it with the help of `xargs`:

```
grep "hello(.*)" file.txt | xargs -I file_name touch file_name
```

**Edit:**

It the input for `xargs` contains a line ending with a backslash (`\`), a file with a newline in its name would be created. The question does not specify what would be the ecpected result in this case.

Example: The input

```
foo\
bar
```

would result in a single file named `foo\nbar`. Adding option `-d '\n'` to the `xargs` command would change the behavior to creating two files `foo\` and `bar`.

Comment: you may also need to add `-d '\n'` to avoid crating a single file `a file\notherfile` on lines like ``a file\`` newline `otherfile`.

Comment: example: `echo -e "hello world\nOne more line" | xargs -I file_name touch file_name` will touch/create two files: `hello world` and `One more line`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
# ~ grep "hello(.*)" file.txt | xargs touch
```

For more refer : `man xargs`

Comment: Notice that using `xargs touch` will tread newlines **as well as spaces** as markers for individual files. Example: `echo -e "hello world\nOne more line" | xargs touch` will touch/create **five** files: `hello`, `world`, `One`, `more`, and `line`.